# Возвращаемая строка содержит нечитаемые символы

Tags: python, кодировка

Использую psycopg2 для работы с Postgress БД. Получаю вот такое вот строковое значение при запросе к БД: " insiderвЂ™s guide to a womanвЂ™s ". Должно быть insider's guide to a woman's. Помогите найти решение

Comment: ну, здесь явно аллергия на символ **'**

Comment: как полечить аллегрию?

Comment: А где кусок кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insiderвЂ™s guide` это так называемые кракозябы ([даже президенты от этого не застрахованы](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhyTheAskObamaTweetWasGarbledOnScreenKnowYourUTF8UnicodeASCIIAndANSIDecodingMrPresident.aspx)), которые получаются когда текст, закодированный в одной кодировке показан в другой несовместимой кодировке:

```
>>> print(u"insiderвЂ™s guide to a womanвЂ™".encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8'))
insider’s guide to a woman’
```

В вашем случае utf-8 текст показывался, используя cp1251 кодировку.

Чтобы уменьшить вероятность подобных ошибок, храните текст как Юникод, а не байты: преобразуйте на входе байты в Юникод, используйте Юникод внутри программы, кодируйте в байты на выходе (если необходимо) ☯:

```
unicode_text = bytestring.decode(character_encoding)
bytestring = unicode_text.encode(character_encoding)
```

Comment: decode('utf-8') решил вопрос. Спасибо