# Byte при печати вывода внешней команды

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, unicode, subprocess

Для лабораторки использую кусок кода:

```
import socket, sys, os, subprocess

ipconfig_res = subprocess.Popen("ipconfig", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in ipconfig_res.stdout.readlines():
    print (line)
```

При запуске в 3.5 выдается список с содержимым типа bytes, преобразовать его в str не получается. Как получить результат без мусора?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно программно информацию о сетевых интерфейсах получить, используя [`netifaces` пакет](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces) (`pip install netifaces`) вместо вызова `ipconfig` и распознавания его вывода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не мусор, а байтовое представление строк, их нужно кодировать (консоль виндовс показывает в кодировке `cp866`), чтобы получить человеко-читаемый вид:

```
ipconfig_res = subprocess.Popen("ipconfig", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in ipconfig_res.stdout.readlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if line:
        print(line.decode('cp866'))
```

Консоль:

```
Настройка протокола IP для Windows
Ethernet adapter VPN - VPN Client:
Состояние среды. . . . . . . . : Среда передачи недоступна.
DNS-суффикс подключения . . . . . :
Ethernet adapter Подключение по локальной сети 4:
Состояние среды. . . . . . . . : Среда передачи недоступна.
...
```

Еще пример:

```
>>> b'\x8d\xa0\xe1\xe2'.decode('cp866')
'Наст'
```

Исправленный, по советам **jfs**, код:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ipconfig_res = Popen("ipconfig", universal_newlines=True, stdout=PIPE)
    for line in ipconfig_res.stdout:
        print(line, end='')
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я пытался конвертировать в utf-8, поэтому получал не то.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК 1- не используйте `.readlines()`. `ipconfig_res.stdout` уже является итератором над строками, разделёнными `b'\n'` в данном случае (даже на Windows). 2- не нужно жёстко прописывать кодировку (`cp866`). Иначе можно неверные результаты получить (без явной ошибки), если запустить тот же скрипт в другом окружении. Старайтесь динамически кодировку получать. [см. мой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497719/23044) 3- Чтобы поддерживать многобайтовые кодировки и перевод строк корректно лучше `TextIOWrapper()` использовать вместо просто `line.decode()`.

Answer (score 2):

`subprocess` модуль использует байты для обмена данными с дочерним процессом.

`b'\r\n'` это текстовое представление (`repr(bytes_object)`) двоичных данных, представленных типом `bytes` в Питоне -- объект, представляющий последовательность двух байт (`0x0d`, `0x0a`) в этом примере. Обычно текстовое представление показывается в интерактивной консоле Питона, где `sys.displayhook` использует `repr()`, чтобы показать объекты по умолчанию (полезно для отладки) или если вы пытаетесь напечатать байты, используя текстовый интерфейс (например, `print(bytes_object)`) -- нужно текст передавать вместо этого.

### Как получить текст из вывода внешней команды

Чтобы получить текст из байт, их необходимо декодировать в Юникод, используя зависящую от команды, её опций и окружения кодировку:

```
text = subprocess.check_output("ipconfig", encoding=encoding)
```

До Python 3.6, [`Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) не принимал `encoding` параметр, поэтому чтобы произвольную кодировку передать, можно явно [`io.TextIOWrapper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) создать. Чтобы построчно вывод прочитать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import io
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

with Popen("ipconfig", stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1) as process:
     for line in io.TextIOWrapper(process.stdout, encoding=encoding):
         # здесь с line можно работать
         print(line, end='')
```

Если передать `universal_newlines=True` в `Popen()`, то [`TextIOWrapper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) используется неявно и соответственно [`locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) кодировка используется, чтобы декодировать байты в текст. Дополнительно, окончания строк нормализируются, например, `'\r\n'` на входе преобразуется в `'\n'`.

Обычно `ipconfig` расположен в [одном из стандартных путей, просматриваемых `Popen()` в поиске исполняемого файла](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24789749/4279) **и** `ipconfig` не является внутренней командой в `cmd.exe`, поэтому `shell=True` не нужно использовать.

### Как определить кодировку, чтобы вывод команды декодировать

*Не нужно жёстко прошивать кодировку окружения, в котором исполняется ваш Питон-скрипт.* Иначе получатся *кракозябы*, если вы запустите команду в окружении, которое может использовать другую несовместимую кодировку символов. См.:

- [Возвращаемая строка содержит нечитаемые символы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/483243/23044)
- [Проблемы с кодировкой Python 2.7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044)

***Используемая кодировка для вывода зависит от команды, её опций и текущего окружения***, например, Питон 3 использует **`encoding=locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`** по умолчанию -- что-нибудь вроде `cp1251` на русской Винде. `cmd.exe` по умолчанию использует OEM code page (см. вывод `chcp` команды) -- что-нибудь вроде `cp866`. Если родительский процесс подключён к той же консоле и `chcp` не был использован для смены кодировки, то можно использовать **`encoding=os.device_encoding(1)`**, который вызывает `GetConsoleOutputCP()` на Windows (это значение может отличаться от **`encoding=ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetOEMCP()`**). `cmd /U` использует `utf-16` кодировку.

Наиболее вероятно, что вывод `ipconfig` можно декодировать, используя `encoding=os.device_encoding(1) or ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetOEMCP()` в этом случае (первое не `None` значение).

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Сейчас разберусь.