# Возврат данных из subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python

Есть скрипт
`p = subprocess.Popen('ssh 168.0.0.1 python subscribe.py command', shell=True)`
он поднимает скрипт питоновский `subscribe.py`, который в цикле возвращает данные без конца.

Как то можно не ожидать выполнение процесса, тем более он бесконечен, а получать данные от него?

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen([sys.executable, '-u', 'child.py'],
           stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as process:
    for line in process.stdout:
        print(line.replace('!', '#'), end='')
```

**child.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time

for _ in range(5):
    print('!!!')
    time.sleep(1)
 
print('Exit. Конец!')
```

Консоль:

```
###
###
###
###
###
Exit. Конец#
```

Comment: 1- указывайте `#!/usr/bin/env python3` для исходного кода на Питоне 3 (как в вашем примере) 2- не нужно декларацию кодировки `coding: utf-8` в Питоне 3 использовать (utf-8 и так кодировка по умолчанию) 3- не нужно `shell=True` использовать (меньше шансов что зловредную команду ваш код выполнит). OP может напрямую `ssh` вызвать без запуска оболочки. 4- не нужно `stdin=PIPE` использовать, если вы ничего не пишете в соответствующую pipe. 5- Используйте `universal_newlines=True` и `print(line, end='')` чтобы текст отобразился. 6- избегайте локально Питон-скрипты как subprocess запускать, лучше ...

Comment: ... [продолжение] вместо этого импортируйте файл как модуль и вызовите соответствующие функции. See [Call python script with input with in a python script using subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30076185/4279) 7- возможно ещё надо `-u` опцию передать дочерней `python` команде -- иначе вывод родителю во время не дойдёт.

Comment: Спасибо за советы, подправил

Comment: 1- universal_newlines=True` включает текстовый режим в Питоне 3. Если вы не понимаете разницу между текстом (Юникодная строка) и двоичными данными (байтами), посмотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497719/23044) 2- можно использовать `for _ in range(5):`, чтобы повторить что-то пять раз

Comment: всё ещё `-u` не хватает, чтобы сразу вывод показывался

Comment: поправил код, чтобы показать как он может выглядить, если все замечания учесть.

Comment: понятно, узнал новое