# Как преобразовать тип bytes в строковые данные в python 3 при использовании модуля subprocess?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

Не могу получить строковые данные из вывода stdout модуля subprocess:

```
import subprocess
cmd = "ping ya.ru"
response = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print(response.stdout)
```

На выходе получаю байтовые данные.

```
b'\r\n\x8e\xa1\xac\xa5\xad \xaf\xa0\xaa\xa5\xe2\xa0\xac\xa8 \xe1 ya.ru [93.158.134.3] \xe1 32 \xa1\xa0\xa9\xe2\xa0\xac\xa8 \xa4\xa0\xad\xad\xeb\xe5:\r\n\x8e\xe2\xa2\xa5\xe2 \xae\xe2 93.158.134.3: \xe7\xa8\xe1\xab\xae \xa1\xa0\xa9\xe2=32 \xa2\xe0\xa5\xac\xef=3\xac\xe1 TTL=54\r\n\x8e\xe2\xa2\xa5\xe2 \xae\xe2 93.158.134.3: \xe7\xa8\xe1\xab\xae \xa1\xa0\xa9\xe2=32 \xa2\xe0\xa5\xac\xef=3\xac\xe1 TTL=54\r\n\x8e\xe2\xa2\xa5\xe2 \xae\xe2 93.158.134.3: \xe7\xa8\xe1\xab\xae \xa1\xa0\xa9\xe2=32 \xa2\xe0\xa5\xac\xef=2\xac\xe1 TTL=54\r\n\x8e\xe2\xa2\xa5\xe2 \xae\xe2 93.158.134.3: \xe7\xa8\xe1\xab\xae \xa1\xa0\xa9\xe2=32 \xa2\xe0\xa5\xac\xef=3\xac\xe1 TTL=54\r\n\r\n\x91\xe2\xa0\xe2\xa8\xe1\xe2\xa8\xaa\xa0 Ping \xa4\xab\xef 93.158.134.3:\r\n    \x8f\xa0\xaa\xa5\xe2\xae\xa2: \xae\xe2\xaf\xe0\xa0\xa2\xab\xa5\xad\xae = 4, \xaf\xae\xab\xe3\xe7\xa5\xad\xae = 4, \xaf\xae\xe2\xa5\xe0\xef\xad\xae = 0\r\n    (0% \xaf\xae\xe2\xa5\xe0\xec)\r\n\x8f\xe0\xa8\xa1\xab\xa8\xa7\xa8\xe2\xa5\xab\xec\xad\xae\xa5 \xa2\xe0\xa5\xac\xef \xaf\xe0\xa8\xa5\xac\xa0-\xaf\xa5\xe0\xa5\xa4\xa0\xe7\xa8 \xa2 \xac\xe1:\r\n    \x8c\xa8\xad\xa8\xac\xa0\xab\xec\xad\xae\xa5 = 2\xac\xe1\xa5\xaa, \x8c\xa0\xaa\xe1\xa8\xac\xa0\xab\xec\xad\xae\xa5 = 3 \xac\xe1\xa5\xaa, \x91\xe0\xa5\xa4\xad\xa5\xa5 = 2 \xac\xe1\xa5\xaa\r\n'
```

При попытке декодирования с помощью .decode('utf-8') возвращается ошибка

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 2: invalid start byte
```

Лучшее на данный момент решение, которое я нашел, это декодировать с игнорированием ошибок и вручную указать кодировку ascii. Но я не уверен, что на других компьютерах и с другими командами код будет давать адекватный вывод данных.

```
print(response.stdout.decode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Символы в командной строке Windows закодированы по кодировочной таблице `cp866`. Декодируйте, используя её:

```
print(response.stdout.decode('cp866'))
```

Кстати, ваш пример можно усовершенствовать, синхронно выводить каждую строку из процесса. То есть, вы не ждете когда процесс отработает полностью, а по мере получения данных из потока вывода, печатаете их на консоль:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "ya.ru"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# синхронный busy spin, работа с потоком вывода, пока процесс не отработает
while True:
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    if output == b'' and process.poll() is not None:
        break
    if output:
        print(output.strip().decode('cp866'))

# когда процесс завершится, poll() вернет код завершения, а не None
rc = process.poll()
```

Comment: При использовании .decode('cp866') программа выводит пустую строку.

Comment: символы могут быть закодированы, используя cp866, но не обязаны (к примеру, `python` при перенаправлении вероятно использует cp1251 на русской Windows). Подробнее см. [мой ответ на дубликат вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497719/23044)