# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 3: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, python-3.5

Почему возникает ошибка при выполнении программы с GPU и нет ошибок при выполнении программы с CPU.

Программа:

```
"""
Created on Tue Feb 14 16:41:40 2017

@author: George
"""
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from theano import function, config, shared, sandbox
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy
import time

vlen = 10 * 30 * 768  # 10 x #cores x # threads per core
iters = 1000

rng = numpy.random.RandomState(22)
x = shared(numpy.asarray(rng.rand(vlen), config.floatX))
f = function([], T.exp(x))
print(f.maker.fgraph.toposort())
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(iters):
    r = f()
t1 = time.time()
print("Looping %d times took %f seconds" % (iters, t1 - t0))
print("Result is %s" % (r,))
if numpy.any([isinstance(x.op, T.Elemwise) for x in f.maker.fgraph.toposort()]):
    print('Used the cpu')
else:
    print('Used the gpu')
```

Выполнение программы с GPU:

```
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (32-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:45:57) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

runfile('H:/Users/George/untitled10.py', wdir='H:/Users/George')
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX 980 (CNMeM is enabled with initial size: 50.0% of memory, cuDNN not available)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-f00bb712112e>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('H:/Users/George/untitled10.py', wdir='H:/Users/George')

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "H:/Users/George/untitled10.py", line 8, in <module>
    from theano import function, config, shared, sandbox

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", line 111, in <module>
    theano.sandbox.cuda.tests.test_driver.test_nvidia_driver1()

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\cuda\tests\test_driver.py", line 31, in test_nvidia_driver1
    profile=False)

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function.py", line 320, in function
    output_keys=output_keys)

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\pfunc.py", line 479, in pfunc
    output_keys=output_keys)

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 1777, in orig_function
    defaults)

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 1641, in create
    input_storage=input_storage_lists, storage_map=storage_map)

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\link.py", line 690, in make_thunk
    storage_map=storage_map)[:3]

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 1003, in make_all
    no_recycling))

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\cuda\__init__.py", line 256, in make_thunk
    compute_map, no_recycling)

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 970, in make_thunk
    no_recycling)

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 879, in make_c_thunk
    output_storage=node_output_storage)

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1200, in make_thunk
    keep_lock=keep_lock)

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1143, in __compile__
    keep_lock=keep_lock)

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1595, in cthunk_factory
    key=key, lnk=self, keep_lock=keep_lock)

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 1142, in module_from_key
    module = lnk.compile_cmodule(location)

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1506, in compile_cmodule
    preargs=preargs)

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\cuda\nvcc_compiler.py", line 362, in compile_str
    nvcc_stdout, nvcc_stderr = decode_iter(p.communicate()[:2])

  File "H:\Users\George\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compat\__init__.py", line 46, in decode_iter
    yield x.decode()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Пользуйтесь оформлением кода и тегами

Answer (score 2):

То что ошибка `UnicodeDecodeError` вызвана `decode_iter(p.communicate()[:2])` строчкой, намекает, что внешняя программа (`nvcc` компилятор, вызванный `theano`) использует кодировку отличную от utf-8 для своего вывода (`x.decode()` использует `sys.getdefaultencoding()` равную `utf-8` на Python 3). Это [известный баг в theano](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/3551).

"Выполнение программы с CPU" не вызывает nvcc компилятор, поэтому вы не видите эту ошибку.

Если обновление до последней версии theano не устраняет ошибку, то посмотрите на значения `nvcc_stdout`, `nvcc_stderr` байтовых строк (с помощью `%debug`) для поиска обходного пути в вашем случае.

[Подробней о том как выбрать выбрать кодировку для subprocess](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497719/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Преодолел ошибку: UnicodeDecodeError:'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 3: invalid continuation byte
изменив в файле:
Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compat__init__.py
строку:
yield x.decode()
на строку
yield x.decode('cp1251').

Результат работы тестовой программы:

Looping 1000 times took 0.998402 seconds
Result is [ 1.23178029  1.61879349  1.52278066 ...,  2.20771813  2.29967761
  1.62323296]
Used the gpu

Георгий.