# Как в python из массива byte в кодировки windows сделать обычную строку? Как декодировать вывод внешней команды

Tags: windows, python-3.x, unicode, subprocess

Есть вот такое код

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_output("ping google.ru"))
```

В ответ печатает массив byte с кракозябрами. А как получить нормальную строку?

Comment: на всякий случай: вместо `print(check_output(..))`, можно просто `check_call(..)` вызвать (по умолчанию `ping` и `print` в одно место печатают).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно знать кодировку, которую использует ping команда, когда её вывод перенаправлен в канал (pipe).

Чтобы автоматически декодировать вывод внешней команды, используя `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` кодировку (ansi code page на Windows, к примеру, cp1251 на русской Винде), можно передать `universal_newlines=True` аргумент (это неочевидное правописание для "включить текстовый режим" параметра. На Питоне 3.7 можно использовать более очевидное `text=True`):

```
from subprocess import check_output

output = check_output("ping example.com", universal_newlines=True)
```

Если вы не на Windows, то следует команду как список передать и указать параметры для ping для вашей системы, чтобы он остановился. На Винде можно строку использовать для указания команды.

Если другая кодировка используется для вывода команды, то можно её явно передать. К примеру:

```
import os

output = check_output("ping example.com", encoding=os.device_encoding(1))
```

В этом случае, cp866 кодировка может быть использована (`GetConsoleOutputCP()`). См. [Byte при печати вывода внешней команды](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497719/23044).

Answer (score -1):

Нужно декодировать используя cp866

```
subprocess.check_output("ваша команда").decode('cp866')
```

Comment: это неверно. Это может работать для одной команды, в одном выбранном окружении, но может сломаться для другой команды, в другом окружении -- люди, которые ваш ответ читают могут другие команды, в другом окружении запускать (отличном от вашего).  К примеру, `python` команда при перенаправлении другую кодировку может использовать, или Windows на другом языке другую OEM cp может иметь. Поэтому не следует жёстко задавать кодировку, когда её программно можно найти . Я это кратко упомянул [в своём ответе и более подробно по ссылке в нём изложено](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/652780/23044)