# Нужно узнать наименование и характеристики железа через Python 3 (проблема с кодировкой)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

Добра всем!

**Что я делаю:** через питона вызываю cmd команду для определения наименования и параметров железа компа. Данные сохраняются во внешний файл, затем считываются.

**Проблема:**

1.Получаемый файл сохраняется через дос в непонятно в каком формате, (через виндовс если напрямую открыть полученный файл, то в нем все нормально отображается).

2.При открытии данного файла через код питона в консоле выводится текст с "бегающими буквами" и через пробелы в формате [A d a p t e r R A M =], который в дальнейшим нельзя использовать.

3. Пробовал сохранять в разных форматах и в разных типах файлов, при считывании одна и та же проблема, при открытии через виндовс все нормально.

**Вопросы:**

А). может посоветуете библиотеку под python 3 чтобы была возможность считывать параметры железа без cmd запросов и без записи во внешние файлы?;

B). как определить кодировку при считывании файла?;

**вот собственно код:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Проверка и определение железа
with open('Jelezo.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    subprocess.run(r'c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /C WMIC.exe /Node:localhost Path Win32_VideoController Get Name^,AdapterRAM /Format:list', stdout=file, check=True)
file.close()
#Считывание данных из файла проверки
open_file = open('Jelezo.txt', 'r')
buftext = open_file.read()
print(buftext)
open_file.close()
```

Спасибо разобрался!

Comment: Старайтесь ограничиваться одной проблемой на вопрос. Если необходимо несколько самодостаточных вопросов задайте. K примеру: 1- "как узнать *блип* характеристику железа, не используя внешнюю wmic команду в Питоне" 2- "какую кодировку указанная cmd команда использует" или "как сохранить вывод wmic в файл в желаемой кодировке"  3- "как прочитать файл в правильной кодировке в Питоне 3" 4- "как напечатать Unicode в консоль на Питоне 3." Так вы и более содержательные ответы можете получить так и больше шансов что ваши  вопросы ещё кому-нибудь могут пригодиться ([цель SO](https://goo.gl/GKHxmL))

Comment: Если вы [кодировку вывода команды узнаете](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497719/23044), то чтобы вывод как текст получить, достаточно `text = subprocess.check_output(command, encoding=encoding)`

Comment: если вы думаете что нашли решение, то опубликуйте его как свой ответ, когда репутация позволит -- [это явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Встроеный модуль platform. Статья про него - [модуль platform](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/platform.html).

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Спасибо, буду держать в курсе!

Comment: Желательно не затягивать. После голосования участников по качеству сообщения, может попасть под удаление.