# check_output. Проблема с кодировкой

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, кодировка, subprocess

```
from subprocess import check_output
import chardet
result = check_output("dir c:", shell = True)
print (chardet.detect(result))
result2 = result.decode("windows-1251")
print(result2)
print(result2.splitlines())
```

Пытаюсь запустить команду cmd и разбить результат по строкам. В разультате получается лист в котором есть не понятные символы. Как решить пробему с кодировкой?

```
{'encoding': 'windows-1255', 'confidence': 0.8130048251836375, 'language': 'Hebrew'}
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 7A6A-0829

 Directory of c:\my_code

15.11.2017  22:16    <DIR>          .
15.11.2017  22:16    <DIR>          ..
15.11.2017  22:26               506 comline.py
15.11.2017  22:16                 0 comline.txt
30.10.2017  23:31           430 080 Database11.accdb
28.10.2017  23:11           217 088 Database2.mdb
31.10.2017  21:54    <DIR>          geodata
23.10.2017  13:32               285 hello.py
24.10.2017  16:43               828 urllib2.py
26.10.2017  08:29               498 urllib3.py
15.11.2017  22:11                 0 привет, как дела.txt
              34 File(s)      8 564 755 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  43 900 641 280 bytes free

[' Volume in drive C has no label.', ' Volume Serial Number is 7A6A-0829', '', ' Directory of c:\\my_code', '', '15.11.2017  22:16    <DIR>          .', '15.11.2017  22:16    <DIR>          ..', '15.11.2017  22:26               506 comline.py', '15.11.2017  22:16                 0 comline.txt', '30.10.2017  23:31           430\xa0080 Database11.accdb', '28.10.2017  23:11           217\xa0088 Database2.mdb', '31.10.2017  21:54    <DIR>          geodata', '23.10.2017  13:32               285 hello.py', '24.10.2017  08:51               575 helpdesk_summary.py', '23.10.2017  16:38           192\xa0864 helpdesk_summary.txt', '26.10.2017  12:33               566 json1.py', '27.10.2017  10:35               538 json2.py', '12.12.2016  23:38           652\xa0714 Library.xml', '28.10.2017  13:39         6\xa0819\xa0048 mbox.txt', '28.10.2017  14:20             8\xa0192 my.sqlite', '21.10.2017  16:27               166 q.py', '21.10.2017  16:26            28\xa0602 regex_sum_41851.txt', '21.10.2017  16:10            28\xa0550 regex_sum_42.txt', '12.11.2017  12:02             1\xa0462 roster.py', '30.10.2017  23:01             1\xa0466 roster0.py', '30.10.2017  23:28             1\xa0450 roster2.py', '30.10.2017  22:58            73\xa0728 rosterdb.sqlite', '30.10.2017  22:53            16\xa0245 roster_data.json', '15.11.2017  21:04               692 sber.py', '12.11.2017  11:56             1\xa0109 sber.txt', '15.11.2017  21:04               301 sber_out.txt', '22.10.2017  10:17               323 socket1.py', '28.10.2017  14:20               646 sql1.py', '12.11.2017  12:02               901 sql2.py', '28.10.2017  23:28                53 sql3.py', '03.11.2017  17:41    <DIR>          text_based_adventure', '29.10.2017  10:03            81\xa0920 trackdb.sqlite', '29.10.2017  10:19             2\xa0700 tracks.py', '12.11.2017  12:02               374 tracks2.py', '24.10.2017  09:23               285 urllib1.py', '24.10.2017  16:43               828 urllib2.py', '26.10.2017  08:29               498 urllib3.py', '15.11.2017  22:11                 0 привет, как дела.txt', '              34 File(s)      8\xa0564\xa0755 bytes', '               4 Dir(s)  43\xa0900\xa0641\xa0280 bytes free']
```

Comment: Где именно непонятные символы? В приведённом вами выводе я вижу, что всё в порядке и все символы нормальные.

Comment: Лист длинный. Если промотать вправо, например, до конца, то увидите: 4 Dir(s)  43\xa0900\xa0641\xa0280 bytes free

Comment: `\xa0` — экранированная запись [неразрывного пробела](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB), вполне понятный и нормальный символ.

Comment: Вижу, что вы имеете ввиду. Действительно, можно пройти по всем элементам листа и заменить "\xa0" на " "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вывод у вас не показывает проблем с кодировкой. `['\xa0']` это текстовое представление Питон-списка — для каждого элемента списка вызывается [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) функция, которая экранирует непечатаемые Unicode символы в строке (элементе списка). [U+00A0 — это неразрывный пробел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB):

```
>>> L = ['A\xa0B']
>>> print(L)     # печатаем список: str(L) вызывает repr('A\xa0B')
['A\xa0B']
>>> print(L[0])  # печатаем сам элемент (строку)
A B
```

Хотя вместо cp1251 (ANSI codepage), я бы ожидал cp866 (OEM) для вывода dir команды в cmd (не тестировал):

```
import ctypes
import os

cmd_codepage = os.device_encoding(1) or ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetOEMCP()
dir_output = check_output(r'dir c:\mycode', shell=True, encoding=cmd_codepage)
```

Если вы хотите получить информацию о файлах в директории, то [можно `os.scandir()` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir). Пример использования `os.scandir()`: [Найти суммарный размер всех регулярных файлов в каталоге, рекурсивно обходя все подкаталоги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461105/23044).

Связанные вопросы:

- [Как json-данные \u0413\u0440... преобразовать в русский текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606885/23044)
- [Byte при печати вывода внешней команды](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/497719/23044)